# Large unwanted vertical gap between divs CSS

Tags: html, css

I have created this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aYn89/2/ which demonstrates my problem, basically I have a large masthead image immediately followed by text, but, possibly due to my use of 'display: inline-block' earlier in the document, there is a large gap between these elements (which is particularly noticeable as I am using a slight gradient on the background) even though I am also using a reset file which sets all margins and padding to 0.

Also, when I inspect the elements in safari there are no gaps or margins either. How can I remove this gap?

HTML:

```
<nav> 
    <div id="logo"> 
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x200" width="50%"> 
    </div> 
    <div id="links"> 
        <a href="#">  Home  </a>  
        <a href="#"> About </a> 
        <a href="#"> Portfolio </a> 
        <a href="#">  Contact </a> 
    </div> 
</nav>

<div id="masthead"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1400x500" width="100%" height="100%">     </div>

<div id="title"> Lorem ipsum blah blah blah </div>

<p> Lorem ipsum blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>
```

CSS

```
nav
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}

#logo
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 0.5%;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
    z-index: 100;
}

#links
{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 1.5%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    font-size: 100%;
    float: right;
    z-index: 100;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    word-spacing: 30px;
}

#links a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0,182,255,1.00);
}

#masthead
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -60px;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#masthead:after { content: " "; display: block; clear: both;}

#title
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 36px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Your `top: -60px;` is what is doing that gap...why the negative for?

Answer (score 3):

You have this

```
#masthead {
display: block;
position: relative;
top: -60px; /* this is probably part of the problem*/ 
z-index: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

When I remove that the 'gap' goes away.

Comment: +1 This is what I found too. This would make the element move 60px up **but still keep the space in the flow**. OP probably wants `margin-top` instead?

Comment: Thanks, this removed the gap but why is the background gradient still formatting strangely? Its almost like the bottom of the gradient is at the top and then after that, goes back to normal. Apologies if the is a silly question, I'm still fairly new to this. EDIT - just noticed I didn't put the background stuff in the original question, but it is in the JSFiddle

Comment: The gradient **stops** at the end of the `body` which is after the <p>> You might want to try adding min-height:100% to the HTML/Body - http://jsfiddle.net/aYn89/4/

Answer (score 0):

Remove one of them, either the **position:attribute** or **top:-60** it will adjust the div with id masthead and the gap will be removed.